# Ellipsis is not working properly for label

Tags: html, css

hi i want that ellipsis style for my label which is inside the UL . i try like adding max width and min width for ul and ellipsis and overflow hidden for label. that time the label content is put down . i have a input and text inside the label. the code i tried is given

```css
ul{
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    max-height: 270px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background:red;
}
label{
   overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:                    ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu main ">
 <li>
 <a href="#">Select All</a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="#">Select None</a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <label>my numbers</label>
 </li>
 <div ">
 <li>
   <input  type="checkbox">
   <label class="">one</label>
 </li>
        <li>
   <input  type="checkbox">
   <label class="">oneeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</label>
 </li>
        <li>
   <input  type="checkbox">
   <label class="">twoooooooooooooooooooo</label>
 </li>

 </div>

 <button >cancel</button>
 <button >Apply</button>
    </ul>
</html>
```

can any one please help me. thanks......

Comment: The ellipsis is showing for me... what would you like it to look like?

Comment: You have a lot of invalid markup. Only permitted child of a `<ul>` is a `<li>`, you have `<div>` and `<button>` as a child of the `<ul>`. Why not use `width: 200px;` if you're going to use the same value for `min-width` and `max-width`?

Comment: The invalid markup is irrelevant to the question.  Your ellipses aren't showing up because there isn't enough text in the labels to overflow.  Add more text and you'll see the ellipses.

Comment: @DanielBeck invalid markup is invalid markup. Simply pointing it out and that it should be corrected. Not meant to be a solution to the problem.

Comment: i want to display the  checkbox and text in same line and. elipssis shoul work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the ellipsis rules to the `li` and set the `label`s  to `display:inline;`

```css
ul {
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  max-height: 270px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

label {
 
  display: inline;
}

li {
 overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<html>
<ul class="dropdown-menu main ">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Select All</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Select None</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>my numbers</label>
  </li>
  <div>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label class="">one</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label class="">oneeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label class="">twoooooooooooo0000oooooooo</label>
    </li>

  </div>

  <button>cancel</button>
  <button>Apply</button>
</ul>

</html>
```

Also note that `<div ">` will cause some pain.
The IDE will hint at invalid syntax, you won't be noticing this if you're colorblind though. 
[image]

Comment: ya this is fine one

Answer (score -1):

You have error in html, this work

```css
ul{
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    max-height: 270px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background:red;
}
label{
   overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu main ">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Select All</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Select None</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>my numbers</label>
              </li>
              <div>
                <li>
                  <input  type="checkbox">
                  <label class="">onefdgdsfandsfñjndjñkadsnfkjsadoyhfgbohdsaingdsag</label>
                </li>
                                   <li>
                  <input  type="checkbox">
                  <label class="">oneeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefdsafndsaifndaipfjndsapfijondsaf</label>
                </li>
                                   <li>
                  <input  type="checkbox">
                  <label class="">twoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooadsfndsapifdsaofndsam0finkdsaf</label>
                </li>
                
              </div>
              
              <button >cancel</button>
              <button >Apply</button>
            </ul>
   </html>
```